# Does the special edition of Fates have all games stored on a single cartridges, or on different ones?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

With Fire Emblem Fates set to release in June in Europe, I've been wondering about the special edition. I know it comes with all 3 games, Birthright, Conquest, and Revelations. The question I'm facing is: Are they all stored on a single cartridge, or does the special edition ship with 3 different ones?

If the special edition ships a single cartridge, I'll pre-order one. If not, I'll just buy the games separately on the eShop instead.

Comment: Technically, this question should be fine. The game's been released in Japan long ago, and it's even available in NA. I'm simply going to assume that the special edition is the same across all regions.

Comment: If the NA market is any indicator, pre-order sooner rather than later; Nintendo won't produce enough to meet demand, so scalpers will try to get most of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this on my [local games store website](https://ebgames.com.au/3ds-208717-Fire-Emblem-Fates-Special-Edition-Nintendo-3DS), which indicates that **yes, all three games will be on one physical game card**:
[image: Fire Emblem Fates Special Edition]

And this on [nintendoeverything.com](http://nintendoeverything.com/fire-emblem-fates-out-in-europe-on-may-20-with-special-edition-and-new-3ds-xl/):
[image: Fire Emblem Fates Special Edition 2]

Comment: Sweet. No need to switch cartridges after all.

Comment: It's also the only way to get Revelations right now; it's download only, and only available..next week?  I think?

Comment: Do you know if this cartridge is equivalent to Birthright or Conquest with the other two paths added to said cartridge as DLC or is it a unique cartridge with a unique title?

Comment: @Leon7C I do not know. I am in Australia where the game hasn't been released yet. I would wager it's a unique title, but perhaps someone with more knowledge can say for sure.

Comment: It's a single cart with all three branches on it; the primary reason I ordered one.